# Export Latex document without shorthands

Tags: overleaf

I use overleaf to compile my Latex documents, so perhaps this is a quesiton about overleaf specifically. I often use a lot of shorthand functions that I define in the preamble (actually in a style sheet) such as "\C" to give "\mathbb{C}" and "\bracket{X}" instead of "\left( X \right)". If I want to send the raw latex to someone though, it is sort of inconvenient for them to learn all of my shorthands, and it makes more sense if I could have overleaf "sub in" all of the short hands, i.e. physically replace "\C" with "\mathbb{C}" everywhere in the document so that I can send it over using only the native commands. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is no general mechanism (TeX never constructs such an expansion) so you need to edit your source with a global replace from `\C` to `\mathbb{C}` etc (you will find several questions on this site about this)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandoc at least to expand some macro definitions:

```
pandoc -f latex -t latex foo.tex -o  foo2.tex
```

Example foo.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\AAA{$\sqrt{x+1}$} 
\newcommand\BBB{\emph{foo}}.
\begin{document}
Text with  \AAA and  \BBB.
\end{document}
```

Result in foo2.tex:

```
Text with \(\sqrt{x+1}\)and \emph{foo}.
```

You can also use the standalone option (-s) to obtain a compilale document and not only the body of the document, but with the long preamble of the default template. However, you can also use a custom template to obtain a simpler preambles.